# CUDA __syncthreads() compiles fine but is underlined with red

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have been working with CUDA 4.2 for a week now and I have a little problem.
When I write the __syncthreads() function it becomes underlined and looks like it is wrong...

Then if I put the mouse on the function it appears a message writing:

> identifier __syncthreads(); is undefined.

but when i compile my project the output form build says:

> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

So I am guessing that everything works fine but the fact that Visual Studio underlines the function is confusing me...How can I make Visual studio to know that this function is defined before the compiling process?

NOTE:The same thing happens with the kernel call: kernel<<<...,...>>> where the third "<" is underlined red too...

I know that this probably is a minor problem but i want to solve it...Thanks a lot!
I am using Visual Studio 2010 on win7 with Cuda 4.2 and Nsight 2.2

Comment: Is the file named something.c or something.cu, whereas the last one indicate a cuda file rather than a plain c file. Have no experience of VS with cuda though.

Comment: @ks6g10... obviously it would be a `cu` file. Where else can you use `__syncthreads` ?

Comment: @sgar91 Yes, ofc you can only use it in a cu file, just that if the file is named .c and not .cu using nvidia nsight, it will register as an error. And somehow it could compile when passed to the nvcc.

Comment: try including `cuda_runtime.h` and/or `device_functions.h` and see if the red underline goes away.  I'm not really suggesting that this is a great solution, because it [may have side effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966469/why-dont-the-cuda-compiler-intrinsics-fadd-rd-etc-work-for-me), but I think this is how the IDE determines what to underline - it's parsing your code for a definition somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I added the following few lines to the top of the cu file and it began to recognize these functions.  For some reason, Intellisense did not pick up this #define:

```
#ifndef __CUDACC__  
    #define __CUDACC__
#endif
```

I lost some color-coding in the code, but I no longer get strange false positive errors.

Comment: This actually works fine for function "__syncthreads();" but problems turn to be there are another 100 more errors "unknown attribute "__device_builtin__".

Comment: Interestingly this worked for me. I'm on VS Community 2013... Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

I am using `CUDA 9.1` and `Visual Studio 2017 15.6.4`. The following code helps me eliminate the "__syncthreads() is undefined" error.

```
//for __syncthreads()
#ifndef __CUDACC__ 
#define __CUDACC__
#endif
#include <device_functions.h>
```

However, this method is not recommended because it may bring unpredictable side effects. Another method to solve this intellisense warning is:

```
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE___
// in here put whatever is your favorite flavor of intellisense workarounds
#endif
```

Reference:
[__syncthreads(); is undefined need a help](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/513485/__syncthreads-is-undefined-need-a-help/)

Answer (score 0):

I have `CUDA 8.0` and `Visual Studio 2015` and I had the same issue. 
The below lines helped me:
After these lines: (already in code)

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
```

I added these lines:

```
//for __syncthreads()
#ifndef __CUDACC_RTC__ 
#define __CUDACC_RTC__
#endif // !(__CUDACC_RTC__)

#include <device_functions.h>
```

It's based on this link: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1009723/__syncthreads-and-atomicadd-are-undefined-in-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this when trying to define the body of `__global__` functions in `.cuh` files.  Moving the body of the functions into `.cu` source-file solved it.

However, it means that some of my templated functions can't use essential things like `__syncthreads()`, because templates might have to be defined in a `.cuh` header.

So, you might need to abandon function templates and instead stick to several functions, each with a slightly different name.

Answer (score -1):

The other solutions either did not solve the same issue occurring in Eclipse 2021-06 with CMake 3.16.3, or produced the following warning with CUDA Runtime Version = 10.1:

```
/usr/include/device_functions.h:54:2: warning: #warning "device_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.
```

The following gave proper highlighting and code completion in Eclipse, and it didn't produce compile warning:

```
#ifndef __CUDACC__
    #define __CUDACC__
    #include <device_functions.h>
#endif
```

Comment: You do understand this question is about Intellisense in Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code, not Eclipse?

Comment: @talonmies Yes. I meant to improve the portability to other IDEs and tool chains. As far as  I understand, solutions similar to `#ifdef __INTELLISENSE___` are preferred, because it is considered only in the IDE but it is ignored during build. But `__INTELLISENSE___` does not work with other IDEs (without Intellisense). Those IDEs commit a similar indexing mistake too. 
My reply could have make more sense as a comment to an answer (and to include these considerations too), but I had no reputation. I am open to delete/improve my answer of course if it is still seen as not adding enough value.