# Why don't the CUDA compiler intrinsics __fadd_rd etc work for me?

Tags: cuda, compiler-errors, nvcc

Why can't I use [these](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE) compiler intrinsics in CUDA 5.0?

In Visual Studio 2010, with CUDA toolkit 5.0 and Nsight installed I am able to compile and run most CUDA code, but `__fadd_ru` etc are reported as undefined. [This](http://pastebin.com/4i1PyLQS) is the code I am trying to compile.

Edit:
It seems that the intrinsics become undefined when either of the following includes are made in the same project:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
```

Comment: What target GPU compute capability are you compiling for?

Comment: 2.1, I think this code is supposed to work back to 1.3 . 
Note - this code is from the CUDA 3 SDK samples

Comment: __fadd_ru() should work with any compute capability. It maps to a native hardware instruction on Fermi and Kepler, and to emulation code on sm_1x. There are no OS dependencies. Have you tried this in a simple test app compiled directly with nvcc (as opposed to Visual Studio projects etc)? If I recall correctly this intrinsic is exported by the file device_functions.h, however the compiler automatically includes that header file when compiling .cu files.

Comment: That does indeed seem to be where they are defined!
cuda_runtime.h doesn't include them unless __CUDAACC__ is defined, so I tried including it manually - unfortunately it still breaks when cuda_runtime.h is included alongside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused (somehow), by including CUDA runtime headers in the project.

The NVCC compiler manages the includes for the cuda runtime automatically, so you don't need to include it manually to compile. The main reason you would add

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
```

to your code is so that your IDE won't show false syntax errors. For some reason adding `device_launch_parameters.h` (which `cuda_runtime.h` depends on), will cause NVCC's intrinsic compiler functions for arithmetic to appear undefined.

So the fix: remove those two includes from the project when you want to compile.